# Hiding part of div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I a having a div element which get populated on a button click, it looks something like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/sample?q1=asd&q2=ads
```

I want to hide particular query parameter (say q1 here). How do I do that ?

I want a solution in eithre js/jquery/html.

**Edit:** Just to be more clear, this is how my div element looks,

```
<div>
  <pre>
  "curl -X GET --header Accept: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/sample?q1=asd&q2=ads"
  </pre>
<div>
```

Comment: You could try mod_rewrite on htaccess - just speculation

Comment: I do not want to achieve redirecting, I want it to be hidden from ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can even change the address displayed to whatever you want with JS:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, "/whatever url");
```

You can also try modifying `location.search`, but it also refreshes the page.

Comment: Note that this will also alter your history state. So if the user navigates away and hits back, he will be requesting this new address from your server.